# How to scan a tag using NFC?

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm simply trying to read the content of a tag. But the longer I research this, the more I feel like the only one that doesn't understand how this works.

Looking through the developer.android.com site, I found the following method:

```
    public String readTag(Tag tag) {
        MifareUltralight mifare = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
        try {
            mifare.connect();
            byte[] payload = mifare.readPages(4);
            return new String(payload, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException while writing Scanner message...", e);
        } finally {
            if (mifare != null) {
                try {
                    mifare.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error closing tag...", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now before I can use that, I need to initialize some things:

```
    public void configScanner()
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        try {
            ndef.addDataType("*/*");    /* Handles all MIME based dispatches. You should specify only the ones that you need. */
        }
        catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
        }
        intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] {ndef, };
        techListsArray = new String[][] { new String[] { Ndef.class.getName() } };
    }
```

Then i simply try to execute it.

```
public void scanClick(View v) 
{
    textview1.setText(readTag(tag));
}
```

I've also added some stuff in the Manifest and my own XML File

Manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
           android:resource="@xml/scan" />
```

scan.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcB</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcF</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.Ndef</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic</tech>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

However, when I execute the code I get a crash when executing `readTag(tag)`. I just don't understand how to get that stuff to work.

As demanded: a LogCat output:

```
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  ... 11 more
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight.get(MifareUltralight.java:94)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at com.example.android_test.MainActivity.readTag(MainActivity.java:108)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  at com.example.android_test.MainActivity.scanClick(MainActivity.java:155)
04-11 17:13:07.650: E/AndroidRuntime(672):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output?

Comment: Alright it says right there what the error is and what causes it. I know little about these particular errors so i suggest you do some searching for InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this in the part of the manifest you posted, but you really need it.

Add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

Comment: its in there, along with  
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />             <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

Comment: Ok then please post the logcat output that says what the error is